# Error in WITH RECURSIVE while troubleshooting hacker rank

Tags: mysql, sql

Summary HackerRank Problem

**(1) Draw Triangle 1**

P(5) :

```
* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

This is example and i have to make this P(20)

```
WITH RECURSIVE stars (n,star) AS(
    SELECT 39,LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *',39)
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT n-2,LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *',n-2)
    FROM stars
    WHERE n>1 
    )

SELECT star
FROM stars
```

I solved question of Draw the Triangle 1 in this way.

**(2) Draw Triangle 2**

P(5):

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * *
```

This is example and i have to make this P(20)

However, this does not work in Draw THE Triangle 2

```
WITH RECURSIVE stars (n,star) AS(

    SELECT 1, LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *',1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+2, LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *',n+2)
    FROM stars
    WHERE n<38
    )

SELECT star
FROM stars
```

```
WITH RECURSIVE stars (n,star) AS(

    SELECT 1,'*'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1, CONCAT(star,' *')
    FROM stars
    WHERE n<20
    )

SELECT star
FROM stars
```

I tried using LEFT() by changing the number just like Triange 1, but the HackerRank site showed a message like 'ERROR 1406 (22001) at line 1: Data too long for column 'star' at row 1' In my personal mysql, I only got OK, but I couldn't see the result table.

If the data is too long and it is an error, shouldn't I meet the same error in the first problem?

Is there something I don't know ?

Comment: In a union, the datatype is determined by the first query. In the query that gives the error it is set by a single character. I'm not sure what mysql does in this case, but it obviously assigns a length too short for what you intend. The solution would be to cast the single character to a string long enough for what you need. You should also use an `ORDER BY` when you select from your cte. In these exercises it's unlikely to return an order you don't expect, but there is no guarantee. In real world applications it can make a big difference; if you want a particular order you have to define it

Comment: Probably easiest to change the first leg in the union to: SELECT 1, '*<space><space>....'     
As @HoneyBadger pointed out, the resulting type is determined by the base case. MySQL appears to silently truncate the result.

Comment: FWIW, postgres 14 will do what you expected, other DBMS will throw an exception since the result does not fit in that type.

Answer (score 1):

Take a good look at outputs of queries for "triangle 1" and "triangle 2".

What is the difference? That's right, rows for the "triangle 2" query are in reverse order.

Which value in the query for "triangle 1" defines the order of rows? That's right, it's `n`.

How can I modify the query for "triangle 1" so that it outputs rows in reverse order? That's right, since the value of `n` in the first row is 39 and the last one is 1 (the rows are ordered by `n` in descending order), just reverse rows order by adding `ORDER BY n`.

So the query for "triangle2" should look like

```
WITH RECURSIVE stars(n, star) AS(
    SELECT 39, LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *', 39)
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT n-2, LEFT('* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *', n-2)
    FROM stars
    WHERE n > 1 
)
SELECT star
FROM stars
ORDER BY n
```

Just [check](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2a0e86f62166aeb8266b5dba4748f1ed) it